# Write dataframe to Azure SQL database from Databricks notebook

Tags: sql-server, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am quite new to Databricks and I was trying to write a data frame into the Azure SQL database. But I am getting an error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.
```

Below is my code:

```
# Imports
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').config("spark.jars", "mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar").getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame 
columns = ["id", "name","age","gender"]
data = [(1, "James",30,"M"), (2, "Ann",40,"F"),
    (3, "Jeff",41,"M"),(4, "Jennifer",20,"F")]

sampleDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(columns)
```

and writing this data frame to the Azure SQL database.

```
sampleDF.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://sqlservername.database.windows.net;databaseName=sqldbname;") \
  .option("dbtable", "df") \
  .option("user", "***") \
  .option("password", "***") \
  .save()
```

When I try to write this data frame, I get the above error.

Answer (score 1):

The version that you're trying to use needs the installation of the external library to your cluster - [its source code repository](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector) lists specific versions that you need to install based on the Spark version used in DBR version that you use. Databricks by default ships with JDBC driver that uses another name - just `sqlserver` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/sql-server)). You should use something like this:

```py
sampleDF.write.format("sqlserver") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://sqlservername.database.windows.net;databaseName=sqldbname;") \
  .option("dbtable", "df") \
  .option("user", "***") \
  .option("password", "***") \
  .save()
```

Comment: I updated my code with your input and got this error ```requirement failed: JDBC url is not allowed in data source options, please specify host, port, and database name options instead.```

Comment: Yeah, I just copied your code but not exactly tested. Check the doc for exact parameters